Check FreeBSD version at compile-time with the preprocessor
I am aware that I can use __FreeBSD__ to detect the operating system, but how do I detect the version of the operating system?
My requirement is to detect whether copy_file_range() function is available, which according to FreeBSD's man page appeared in FreeBSD 13.0.

According to this page, the macro __FreeBSD_version is defined in <sys/param.h> that contains the value of the current operating system version.

That's some good documentation. Except that now I see around 100 or more values to detect FreeBSD 13.0 revisions. :) Perhaps 1300526 would be the correct one, as that is the last revision value before FreeBSD 13.1?

@Harith I'd try going for the earliest 13.0 release possible. Maybe you can look at the FreeBSD source to see in what revision exactly the function was introduced? It probably doesn't matter much since the current FreeBSD version is 14.1 :)

@Harith this site lets you check manpages for each FreeBSD version. The earliest version I could find that has the function is 13.0 RELEASE, so requiring the version to be 1300000 should work

as that is the last revision value before FreeBSD 13.1? As I understand, #if 1300000 <= __FreeBSD_version  && __FreeBSD_version < 1301000 should detect FreeBSD versions 13.0.
